# How to make own Scala UI Events

Tags: swing, events, scala, scala-swing

I am currently developing my first bigger Scala Swing [project](https://github.com/scan/MonMaker), and I have written my [own component](https://github.com/scan/MonMaker/blob/master/src/main/scala/maker/gui/tiles/TileSetPane.scala) as a part of the tile map editor, in which the user chooses the tiles.

Just as a combo box emits some sort of event when another element is selected, I want this component to do the same, with my own case classes. I have not found any article or tutorial on this topic.

In further notice, how can I also write a component that publishes the events of sub-components. So that it just reaches them through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps look at other projects extending scala-swing. For example there is [ScalaSwingContrib](https://github.com/benhutchison/ScalaSwingContrib); I think looking at the [`ColorChooser`](https://github.com/benhutchison/ScalaSwingContrib/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalaswingcontrib/ColorChooser.scala) component and the associated [`ColorChooserEvent`](https://github.com/benhutchison/ScalaSwingContrib/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalaswingcontrib/event/ColorChooserEvent.scala) is a good starting point, as this is a fairly simple component.

```
import javax.{swing => js}
import js.{event => jse}
import java.awt.Color
import scala.swing._
import event.Event

class ColorChooser(initialColor: Color) extends Component {
  ...
  override lazy val peer: js.JColorChooser = 
    new js.JColorChooser(initialColor) with SuperMixin

  peer.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(new jse.ChangeListener {
    def stateChanged(e: jse.ChangeEvent) {
      publish( new ColorChangeEvent(peer.getColor))
    }
  })
}

case class ColorChangeEvent(c: Color) extends Event
```